# ARC - UIWebView/UIViewController is sticking around in memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

My old UIWebViews seem to be sticking around when using ARC, for some reason they still show up in OSX Safari's Developer Tools even after I've come out of their UIViewController.

I'm allocating an transitioning to a view controller that contains a UIWebView, like this:

```
    //Create settings view/tabbar
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[NoRotateTabBarController alloc] init] ;

    StyleViewController *styleTab = [[StyleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyleViewController" bundle:nil];
    styleTab.tabBarItem.title = @"Style";
    styleTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeIcon.png"];

    NSArray *tabsArray = @[styleTab];
    tabController.viewControllers = tabsArray;

    prevView = self.window.rootViewController;

    [UIView
        transitionWithView:self.window
        duration:0.5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
        animations:^(void) {
            BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
            [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
            self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
            [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
        }
    completion:nil];
```

I'm coming out of that view like this:

```
    [UIView
        transitionWithView:self.window
        duration:0.5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
        animations:^(void) {
            BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
            [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
            self.window.rootViewController = prevView;
            [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
        }
    completion:nil];
```

The UIWebView (int StyleViewController) is being created this way:

```
    @implementation StyleViewController
    UIWebView *webView;

    //viewDidLoad
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = false;
    webView.alpha = 0;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webView.opaque = false;

    @end
```

However, I notice that when I inspect in Safari, the old UIWebViews appear to be stacking up, and the old ones still show in the menu. Is this a bug in Safari's Developer tools? Is there a way to ensure that my UIWebViews get released?

Comment: Is there a  reason you aren't alloc this way?    NoRotateTabBarController *tabController = [[NoRotateTabBarController alloc] init] ;

Comment: That is how I'm allocating it...?

Comment: It might help if you clarified - I see no UIWebViews in your code. Also, what does this signify "OSX Safari's Developer Tools"? I assume its something somewhat outside the ordinary as I've not heard of it...

Comment: Desktop Safari comes with Developer Tools that allow you to inspect UIWebViews, like you would a webpage in Safari. Also edited to include how I'm creating my UIWebView.

Comment: @mattcurtis , why don't you simply profile using instruments (allocation tool) to check if your UIWebView becomes deallocated or not? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was delegates. I was using [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge), and it does some funky stuff with delegates, so I needed to get rid of it first. Doing this in my `viewWillDisappear` selector kept them from getting retained:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { /* or dealloc */
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    _bridge = nil;

    //UIWebView #1
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
    webView.delegate = nil; webView = nil;

    //UIWebView #2
    [textView removeFromSuperview];
    textView.delegate = nil; textView = nil;
}
```

Thank you for all the excellent answers, regardless!

Comment: Even though you answered your own question, you should select it so that other readers immediately know where to go.

Comment: @DavidH Whoops, I think when I originally answered this it wouldn't let me and I forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you experience this, what you find is that something is retaining the views. Add breakpoints or log messages to the dealloc method of all your custom subclasses, and see if any of them are getting dealloc'd. If so, and one of them is the owner of the UIWebViews, well, you'll have to dig.

If you are just plain stuck and getting nowhere, then dup your app (the whole folder), and in the above code get rid of all the complex classes (one by one) and use a simple UIViewController subclass with log messages in the dealloc. With really simple classes you should be able to get the project so everything deallocs. They start putting your custom class back, one by one, until the dealloc stops. This should help you narrow down where the problem is.

Aa you probably know, block retain cycles, or using strong delegates, can cause problems. I did notice that UIWebView explicitly states that you should set the delegate to nil if you are using one, before you dispose of it. [Also NSURLConnection retains the delegate.]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having a retain cycle due to your references to `self.window.rootViewController` in your animations block.

With ARC, blocks are copied, and thus captures also the variables you use inside the block. So you need to create a `__weak` reference to self for use inside your block.

Like so:

```
__weak SomeObjectClass *weakSelf = self;

SomeBlockType someBlock = ^{
    SomeObjectClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil)
    {
        // The original self doesn't exist anymore.
        // Ignore, notify or otherwise handle this case.
    }
    else
    {
        [strongSelf someMethod];
    }
};
```

See here in the Blocks section: [ARC Best Practices](http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html)